# Is it possible to pick our own color theme (e.g. dark mode) in MMSE, like we can in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

As in Stack Overflow it's possible to choose the colour theme for the page, is it possible to implement that feature even in MatterModeling?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow currently allows us to pick one of three color themes:

[image]

This might even increase in the near-future, as indicated by [this post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386102/391772) which is currently "featured" network-wide.

These color themes are not yet available on MMSE:

[image]

[This answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345762/391772) was last updated in May 2022 and currently says that dark mode is only available in Stack Overflow (and its versions in other languages).

It's possible to implement a "hack" though, which gives you dark mode on SE sites that are not part of the Stack Overflow series, one example being described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284738/391772).

More information can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412644/1271772) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/1271772), the first of those links has a [comment]( "For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network. Many of the designs on our sites have been around long enough that converting them to dark mode would require redoing the artwork completely. We would prefer to avoid giving anyone across our network a substandard experience and we don’t want to change those elements without the input of these communities. ") that point us to a quote from [30 March 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/?_ga=2.119700044.555774771.1674775405-502571171.1594482543):

> "For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network. Many of the designs on our sites have been around long enough that converting them to dark mode would require redoing the artwork completely. We would prefer to avoid giving anyone across our network a substandard experience and we don’t want to change those elements without the input of these communities."